# How do you intercept Bluetooth button events from a Parrot B350-XT Bluetooth headset?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

My Bluetooth headset (Parrot B350-XT) has 4 buttons:

1. Volume Up
2. Volume Down
3. Power button
4. "Parrot" button

I am creating an Android application (OS 4.4.2) running on Samsung's SM-T230NU.

I would like my application to be able to receive notification when any of the above 4 buttons are pressed including the type of button press (long press, short press). My application will interpret these events in context. The application I am developing is a softphone and I would like the following hook up between button events and softphone actions. This is just
an example:

1. User presses vol down. Action: volume is decreased
2. User presses vol up. Action: volume is increased
3. User presses 'parrot' button while there are no calls active. Application is brought to foreground
4. If an inbound call happens and user presses 'parrot' button, then call is answered
5. If an inbound call is active and user presses 'parrot' button, then call is hung up

So far I've looked through Android SDK, stackoverflow posts and various implementations but I haven't been able to figure out how it should be done.

Answer (score 2):

I have checked their official website, It seems that this device cannot be programmed. They have been provided an APP to communicate with their product -- VXi BlueParrott App.
Anyway, you can try TechnicalSupport@vxicorp.com.